# How to plot multiple maps in a single model

Tags: plot, netlogo

Colors of my patches are currently decided by sum of array elements and it looks like
[this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nfiV.png)

I need to plot another 10 maps like the one above but with different colors of patches.

Is there a way to do that? I couldn't find anything useful on google/models library

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you want to do? "plot another 10 maps but with different colors of patches" is pretty vague, it could mean a lot of different things.

Comment: Sorry for my grammar, english is not my native language. I add one example to clarify my point..    So, the patches own 2 variables, weight and height. On the one 'map' we would like to color the patches like this. The color of patches with weight > 100 lb would be green and below 100 lb would be blue. But on the second 'map' we want to visualize the height variable, so the patches with height > 1.58m would be red and below 1.58m would be black.

Comment: Do you want both maps to be visible simultaneously? In NetLogo, you can only have one "view" of the world.

Comment: ah, that's a shame :(.